# Vacuum energy and cosmic graviton background

Tags: cosmology, vacuum, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, cosmological-constant

What is the best way to show that vacuum energy (the cosmological constant) cannot be the same as a cosmic graviton background (or cosmic gravitational radiation background)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A cosmological constant is equivalent to the universe being filled with a perfect fluid that has the [equation of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state_%28cosmology%29) $p=-\rho$.

The equation of state for a universe filled with radiation such as gravitons and photons, or with ultra-relativistic matter, is $p=\rho/3$.

Note that these differ even in the sign of the pressure! In short, these two things have very different gravitational effects. A cosmological constant makes the [Friedmann scale factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations) for a spatially-flat universe like ours expand exponentially: $a\propto e^{Ht}$. A relativistic gas makes it expand as a power law: $a\propto t^{1/2}$. The former expansion gets faster and faster; the latter gets slower and slower.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer: short and clear. Please allow one more question: is the equation of state =/3 for a graviton fluid also correct if the horizon is not a boundary, but if the horizon continuously produces gravitons and injects them into the universe?

Comment: 2. In fact, I have a second question. Could vacuum energy be due to *virtual* gravitons? Would they have the correct equation of state?

Comment: Regarding the horizon... I can’t think of any reason why it would matter whether real gravitons came from a horizon or not. But I don’t think cosmological horizons produce real gravitons or other particles. Is this a mainstream idea?

Comment: As far as I know, “zero-point” fluctuations of any quantum field (similar to the ground state energy of a harmonic oscillator) cause vacuum energy with the same form as a cosmological constant. The problem is that this energy is generally infinite (because there are an infinite number of modes of vibration with arbitrarily large frequency), or much larger than the cosmological constant (if you do a cut-off at some reasonable frequency), or zero (if you have supersymmetry so bosonic and fermionic contributions cancel).

Comment: Nobody has a convincing way to get the right value of a very small but nonzero cosmological constant from vacuum fluctuations of gravitons or other fields.

Comment: On the horizon, are you thinking of the Unruh effect?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about the Unruh effect and all the similar ones. - In any case, thank you for the clear answers. They are very useful.